# How i can use value_counts in many columns in an efficient way?

Tags: python

i'm looking for use value_counts in many columns and i know that i can use `df.island.value_counts()` but i want a loop or something more efficient to don't put the name of each column of the DataFrame. It's important to say that I know the specific columns with i want apply this function. The code that i'm using is:

```
data_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cmdlinetips/data/master/palmer_penguins.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(data_url)
df.select_dtypes(object).head() # I use this to know the columns that has variables categorical. I want this because i'm looking to know what categorical variables they has, and that is why i'm using value_count

df.island.value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
categories = df.select_dtypes(object).head() # this is a dataframe object
categorical_columns = categories.columns # this is an iterable which contains strings of column headers

counter_dict = {}

# loop through each column, add values to dict
for column in categorical_columns:
    counter_dict[column] = df[column].value_counts()
    # each item in dict has column title as key and value_counts series as value
```

Comment: Thatcher thanks!! your suggestion works perfectly in my code!!